# SQL query returning negative values following GMT DST change

Tags: mysql, group-by

This SQL query has begun to return negative values.

**Query:**

```
SELECT 
  DATE(date_created),
  TIME(date_created),
  TIME(completed_time),
  SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(completed_time,date_created)))), 
  AVG(TIMEDIFF(completed_time,date_created)) 
FROM leads 
WHERE date_created > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 60 DAY) 
GROUP BY DATE(date_created), tier
ORDER BY date_created DESC
```

**Error**

```
Bad format for Time '-00:06:33.6250' in column 4
```

I can group by 'DATE(date_created)' or by 'tier' but when I add both the error occurs 'GROUP BY DATE(date_created), tier'

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Confusion here. By its very nature UTC (GMT) doesn't flip from daylight to winter time. What are the data types of your columns?

Comment: That 'group by' has got me very suspicious... what happens if you take it out?

Comment: @tomMelly If I remove 'GROUP BY DATE(date_created), tier
ORDER BY date_created DESC' it returns a result, but it is an average for the entire data set, which is of no use. I know the base query is sound as we have been using it for a long time before it recently stopped working.  https://app.screencast.com/LNCdX116np58T

Comment: @O.Jones They are DATETIME columns. https://app.screencast.com/2mThXovSJWIKx

Comment: @TomMelly I suspect it works with the GROUP BY removed because the larger dataset is pre the DST change so it averages out the negative values to create a positive.

Comment: *They are DATETIME columns.* Timezone operations are NOT applied to DATETIME columns. They're applied to TIMESTAMP columns only.

Comment: Unrelated to the error mentioned in your question but ...  _"I know the base query is sound"_ - no it isn't. Your current query is _almost certainly_ non-deterministic and should be triggering a `1055` error. Please read and digest [MySQL Handling of GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html). If you are not getting this error it is because [`ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) is disabled, which it shouldn't be.

Comment: @Akina It appears I have misunderstood the problem. It may be correlation not causation that this stopped working on the 29th when DST came into force.

Comment: @user1191247 tbh I don't think it barfs with only_full_group_by (although it probably should). I adapted the query to run against a table on my system (OFGB enabled), and it runs, but the values returned look wrong.

However, completely agree that there's something 'off' about the combo of group by and the way it handles the fields.

Comment: @user1191247 You are correct ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is disabled and the query did work, even though not best practice.

Comment: @TomMelly DST was clearly a red herring and the problem is GROUP related . I dropped the 'tier' from 'GROUP BY DATE(date_created), **tier**' and now get results.

I don't know whether this should now be a new question, but if my method of grouping by two columns is not valid, how should this be performed?

Comment: It sounds like there are some tiers where `completed_time` is less than `date_created`. When averaged across tiers it is not significant enough to turn the overall AVG negative, but when grouped by tier it is. The [`ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) issue is not really a question of _"best practice"_, it is more about writing valid and deterministic queries. The time values in your current query have no meaning, as it is arbitrary which values will be returned.

Comment: Simple example - [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/kcrUttgp)

Comment: Bit hard to recommend what to do here without knowing a bit more. I guess the main question is "why are you grouping by a date, and are you expecting this date to be unique for each record?"

I suspect you need neither the 'group by' nor the 'avg' (or indeed, any aggregate functions)

Comment: I can run the query with 'GROUP BY DATE(date_created)' and it works and I can also run it with 'GROUP BY tier' and it works. The problem only occurs when I run them together. Which along with the fact that this fell over on the 29th Oct would point to there being a problem with one or more tiers where completed_time is less than date_created on the 29th Oct. So, it is actually a DST issue after all because leads that started processing around 02:59am on the 29th Oct will have been reported as completing at approx 02:02am.

Comment: Are you expecting the same number of rows in your output as in your input? i.e. if you have 20 rows where "WHERE date_created > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 60 DAY)" is true, are you expecting 20 rows of output?

Bottom line - without knowing why you are grouping, it's hard to advise.

Comment: @TomMelly I'd expect less rows. A 'tier' is a partner that buys our leads and each partner ('tier') could buy 1 or 100 leads a day. This query has run for years without issue. What has happened this year is when the clocks changed there were 8 leads that started processing before and finished after the DST change, resulting in a negative 'TIMEDIFF' https://app.screencast.com/PncMukGViq3by. We haven't been caught by this before as the AVG of the 'GROUP BY tier' always stayed positive, but this year a partner ('tier') bought one lead that day and it was one of the 8 caught in the time warp!

Comment: @user1191247 I would definitely be using your 'Dirty' fix, but luckily we don't get a huge amount of leads processing at 2am, so I can just change the 8 of them manually.

Comment: Well guys, this was a bit of a messy journey we've been on and not the most satisfying of fixes. But, none the less your input got me to the root of the problem and now our company dashboards have just sprung back to life. Many thanks for all the help!

Comment: Glad you got there in the end. Another dirty solution is to change the TIMEDIFF to `TIMEDIFF(completed_time, IF(date_created > completed_time, date_created - INTERVAL 1 HOUR, date_created))` but it could mask other issues.

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem with one or more 'tiers' where the 'completed_time' was less than 'date_created' on the 29th Oct due to Daylight Saving Time. Leads that started processing around 01:59am on the 29th Oct will have been reported as completing at approx 01:02am.

The fix was to update the affected 'completed time' rows adding +1hr.

(A dirty solution to this was provided in the comments below)